# Mongodb: Query documents by a sub-document field (GeoJSON)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, geojson, mongoose-schema

I have three document schemas in my database model: pointSchema (just a GeoJSON Point definition), PlaceSchema (this is a real place, like a nightclub) and EventSchema (this will store data related to events like parties and festivals).

But I'm having some problems. I need to query the Events documents according to his location, but, that location data is stored in a sub-document that have a relationship with the Event.

Below are my schemas definitions:

```
const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true
  }
});

const PlaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    location: {
      type: pointSchema,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
);
PlaceSchema.index({
  name: 'text',
  location: "2dsphere"
});

const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    place: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Place'
    }
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
)
EventSchema.index({
  name: 'text'
})
```

I can filter the Places documents just using something like this:

```
db.Places.find({ 
    location: {
        $geoWithin: { 
            $centerSphere: [ 
                [ -28.824342, -49.218433 ],
                100 / 6378.1 
            ] 
        } 
    }
})
```

But I can't do the same when I try to filter the events. I already tried a query like this:

```
db.Events.find({ 
    "place.location": {
        $geoWithin: { 
            $centerSphere: [ 
                [ -28.824342, -49.218433 ],
                100 / 6378.1 
            ] 
        } 
    }
})
```

but that solution doesn't works. Someone could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `location` key exists in place schema and you have just made reference to it inside the events.

Comment: Hello Anthony, sure...But I can't use that key (that is inside a nested document) in my event filter?

Comment: Please explain what do you need? what output do you need because you are going in wrong direction here. You are trying to access child/parent fields with the reference key.

Comment: the `place` in the event document is it just an `ObjectId` or the place document itself added as a subdocument?

Comment: Hello @AbdelrahmanHossam, the place is just a objectId in event document.

Answer (score 0):

Since `place` in your `event` document is just an `ObjectId` then you have one of 2 choices

1. multiple finds

```
let places = db.Places.find({ 
   location: {
       $geoWithin: { 
           $centerSphere: [ 
               [ -28.824342, -49.218433 ],
               100 / 6378.1 
           ] 
       } 
   }
}, { _id:1 }) // get the places _ids

let events = db.events.find({
   place: { $in: places.map(p => p._id) }
}) // get events that has the places _ids
```

2. aggregation

```
const stages = [
{ $geoNear: {
   near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -28.824342, -49.218433 ] },
   distanceField: "distance",
   spherical: true,
   maxDistance: 100 / 6378.1
} },
{ $lookup: {
   from: 'events',
   localField: '_id',
   foreignField: 'place',
   as: 'events'
} }
];

let result = db.places.aggregate(stages);
```

Comment: Hello man, thanks to reply. I tried your second suggestion, using aggregation. But I'm facing this issue:

    MongoError: no geo indices for geoNear

Comment: @RenanCunha do you have more than one geo index on places collection? if so you need to specify the geospatial indexed field to use when calculating the distance.

Comment: Hi, at places collection I have just an index: PlaceSchema.index({
  location: "2dsphere"
});

Comment: Try to double check if the index was actually created. I have checked on my side and it is working as expected.

try to run this in mongo shell (after using the correct db)
`db.places.getIndexes()`
[
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "test.places"
 },
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "location" : "2dsphere"
  },
  "name" : "location_2dsphere",
  "ns" : "test.places",
  "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
 }
]